# php query - Background color changes

Tags: php, html

What I want is to change the color of a cell in a table based on the value that is returned by the query.

what I have done is this --
In the style

```
 .priority_1, priority_-1, priority_0{
    background-color: green;
    color:green;
    }
    .priority_4, .priority_5, .priority_6, .priority_7, .priority_-4, .priority_-5, .priority_-6, .priority_-7{
        background-color: red;
        color:red;
}
```

and in the body - cell

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SHOP, FORMAT(VARMP,0) AS value FROM recordstable WHERE SHOP='1' AND Month='1' AND Type='TCheck'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


    $priority = $row['value'];

echo "<td class=\"priority_{$priority}\"><center>";
echo $priority . "";
}
?>
</td>
```

this gives me what i want however, what if the value falls outside the range - if i get a value of 43 I want it red. but the .priority will only chnage to red for 7 to -7. how can i do a range easy easy style. without doing priority 1 - 100 plus an minus.

Comment: I suggest applying a class dynamically, and leave your styling up to your CSS.

Comment: Won't the background color need to be set in the `<td>` css?

Comment: Just curious, should the `while` loop be inside the `<td>` element or should you be generating a new `<td>` element for each returned result. The reason I ask, is that if it's all in the `<td>` element, you'll have to wrap the returned results individually to change their colors. Otherwise the `<td>` will have one color, green or red...

Comment: Anybody want to expand a little on above comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create that many classes. If I've understood correctly, you probably need something like:

**CSS:**

```
.priority_green{
    background-color: green;
    color:green;
}

.priority_red{
        background-color: red;
        color:red;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $priority = $row['value'];

    $class = 'green';
    if($priority >= -7 and $priority <= 7){ $class = 'red'; } //from 7 to -7 only

    echo "<td class=\"priority_$class\"><center>";
    echo $priority . "";
    //don't forget to close <center> and <td> and you also don't have rows - just a note
}
```